# Angular component class selector, case not preserved

Tags: angular, selector, case-sensitive

I would need some help with a Components selector.
I try to add the class .Home_root like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: '.Home_root',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
```

But what I see render in my browser is:

```
<div class="home_root ng-star-inserted" _nghost-c1="">...</div>
```

So, my class name is lowered case.

Is there any way that I can preserve the classname, exactly the way I wrote it? What causes this transormation?
I tried to find some answer on the web without luck.

My angular code version is 5.2.0

I apologize in advance, if I do not provide enough code to locate the cause of the issue. Since I am still not familiar with angular, I do not even know what part of the code I should post.

Comment: Ingo Bürk, classnames and ids are case sensitive.

Answer (score -2):

The selector is the name of your component on HTML file, you can't do that.

The right way.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home-root',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
```

Your HTML will render this.

```
<home-root></home-root>
```

If you want to change your style root selector your can do this in your CSS file.

```
:host {
 //your style here will be applied to the root selector.
}
```

Comment: Components don't have to use tag selectors.

Comment: Will, This is not exactly what I was asking, but your information about :host is very useful. So thanks a lot for that!